# Как получить массив значений атрибута из HTML-страницы

Tags: java, html, атрибуты

Добрый день. Есть обычная html-страница. На ней есть атрибут с именем x. Допустим на странице 40 значений этого атрибута. Мне нужно получить массив всех значений этого атрибута на странице. Как это лучше всего сделать?

Comment: getElementsByAttribute(x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Elements elements = document.getElementsByAttribute(x);

for(Element el : elements){
            System.out.println(el.attr(x));
        }
```

Comment: Чудесно, спасибо!